# Self answer incorrectly deleted?

Tags: support

I've looked at it a few times now and not sure what I'm missing - why was [this user's self answer](https://superuser.com/a/575138/138343) deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was auto-flagged for low quality. I guess it wasn't apparent that it's a self-answer.

I wouldn't want to go in and just reverse the deletion right now, in case I'm missing something.

Comment: It's short and I can certainly see how it might have tripped the filter, but doesn't seem to be incorrect in any way, which is why I was confused. If no-one can point out any obvious issues we're both missing, guess the deletion can be reversed eventually.